# Aligning fullscreen image divs on horizontal scrolling page

Tags: html, css

I want to make a horizontal scrolling website, with fullscreen image divs. The divs will contain text, which is why I've used background-images.
I can’t find a way, to place the divs neatly next to each other.

I’ve tried **float** and **inline-block**, but either it didn’t work or the divs didn’t align properly.

I’ve made a jsfiddle to show my code. Objective is to get **“A"** next to **“B"**.

[Here's the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pb8py3y2/7/)

```
<div class="a">Text</div>
<div class="b">Text</div>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE** – height of image must be 100%. More than two divs will be used on the website, and they will all vary in width. [Here's a sketch of what I try to achieve](http://oi65.tinypic.com/90unsz.jpg)

Comment: This is an awesome question!

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Thanks @www139! I hope we'll find a nice solution!

Comment: Yes @HarshSanghani, I've replied to your post underneath.

Answer (score 3):

Put `display:inline-block` to your classes `.a and .b`.

```
.a,
.b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb8py3y2/9/)

Comment: I tried resizing my window, the `divs` are next to each other with a horizontal scroll. Can you please tell me what does not work if the window is resized, so that I could correct my solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Alorika, I've tried this method as well, and the problem is, that it's not responsive, when resizing. The gaps are almost inevitable. There is certain tricks to remove them, but they don't really work in every scenario.

Comment: @Casper It's important to note, users won't typically be resizing the window. It works if you refresh inbetween the resizing.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated the day before Christmas :)**
Use background size (if the position of the image is skewed, you can use background position).

There is actually no possible way to get the image to cover the entire thing without having it get cut off somewhere or skew the proportion of the image (creating a bad, blurry image). Your best bet is to get the image to cover the viewport area with some sides cut off and then center the subject of the image with `background-position:x(%);`.

Google Drive's "intro" website seems to have the behavior that you are after with the images. Take a good look at the first "panel" and the styles applied with the background image. Is that what you want? It seems pretty close.

To experiment with different background-size behavior, I suggest that you checkout this play-it page http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=200px.

Try this :)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*remove annoying margin created by display:inline-block;*/
  font-size: 0;
}
.a,
.b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
.a {
  background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/2wqv7fd.jpg);
}
.b {
  background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2lborxv.jpg);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="a">Text</div>
    <div class="b">Text</div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @www139, this method is actually pretty close to what I want to achieve. However, I need the images to be fully visible in height.

Answer (score 3):

Using inline-block without white space relies on the HTML markup not having gaps between two elements. `<div class="a">Text</div> <div class="b">Text</div>` would result in a space between the two divs.

To achieve a background-image filling the width and height of a div, we can use `background-size: 100% 100%; background-position:center;`. Alternatively, we can use `background-size:cover;` if we want the background-image to crop rather than stretch.

UPDATED Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v2wxv73e/2/

```
 #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.a,
.b {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Use `float:left` and `width:50%;` when `#wrapper` has `width: 200%.`

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v2wxv73e/

Comment: This would only work if there were two divs. Works for the OP but may not be the best idea in the long run (+1 anyway :) )

Comment: True! Definitely a good idea to note that this relies on a static knowledge of the containing number of divs - or updating both containing and inner divs with javascript accordingly which is not ideal. Cheers @www139

Comment: Thanks for your input @RepeatQuotations, I've added some more details in the post. There will be more than two divs on the final site. They will vary in width, and should have 100% in height. Any idea how I might get that done? I apologize for the lack of information.

Comment: If the containing elements vary in width, we need to figure out how we want to determine the width. Is it based on the contents, width of the screen or height?

Comment: @RepeatQuotations, I've made a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve. I hope it's helpful! Appreciate it! Check the following link http://oi65.tinypic.com/90unsz.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I solved your issue, Please change your css with following :-

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.a,
.b {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.a {
  background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/2wqv7fd.jpg);
}

.b {
  background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2lborxv.jpg);
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Harsh Sanghani, I've tried this method as well, and the problem is, that there's white gaps between the images. They're almost inevitable. There is certain tricks to remove them, but they don't really work in every scenario.

Comment: I have update my answer which has not any white gap between images, Please try again.

Comment: This is better – but the images is not fully visible / not 100% in height. If only we could get the last tweak on it, we're there!

Comment: I have edited answer one more time, Can you please try again?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. However, in this solution, the images gets distorted, when the browser is resized.

Comment: if you need to display full image then i think these problem occur otherwise you have to take image as <img> tag and then make it resize with browser.